# Rails reading from settings.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi is it possible to read from an controller the settings yml? Im using rails 4.2.0

I want to store some global information in the settings.yml to display those in the view

at the moment I try this way:

```
settingsfile = File.read(Rails.root + "./config/settings.yml")
settingsfile = YAML.load(settingsfile)
settingsfile["default"]
```

works but when I want to go deeper

```
settingsfile["default"]["info"]
```

its empty

Yml File

```
default:
  supported_languages:
    de: Deutsch
    fr: Francais
    en: English
    it: Italiano
    sv: Svenska
    pt: Português
    nl: Nederlands
    es: Español
  production:
  info:
    version: 2.0.0
    datum: 11.05.2015
```

Comment: Nothing at the moment, Of course I can try a read yml how its done like this in application.rb `File.read(Rails.root + "./config/settings.yml")` But probably there is something smarter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try:

```
@settingsvariable = Settings.default.supported_languages.de
```

This approach worked in my app.

Answer (score 5):

without using gem..you can use something like ..

**your dev/config/email.yml**

```
 development:
  :address: smtp.service.com
  :port: 25
  :user_name: mike@gmail.com
  :password: mikepassword
production:
  :address: smtp.gmail.com
  :port: 587
  :authentication: plain
  :user_name: mike@gmail.com
  :password: mikepassword
  :enable_starttls_auto: true
```

**you can load this yml file simply like....**

```
  email_settings = YAML::load(File.open("#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/email.yml"))
 ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = email_settings[Rails.env] unless email_settings[Rails.env].nil?
```

also you may use - `Rails::Application.config_for(:email)` as shown in the [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#custom-configuration) for Rails 4+ onwards.

Comment: This works beautifully and is much better than using an additional gem.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the gem [rails_config](https://github.com/railsconfig/rails_config).

Comment: Thanks, but Isn't there any way without an aditional gem?

Comment: Well, at least you need `yaml` or something. You don't want implement yet another yaml parser, do you?

Comment: Can you post the content of your .yml file, please?

Comment: I've copied your .yml file and tried your ruby code. It works perfect for me. Maybe you should pay attention to the indent in your .yml file?

Answer (score 1):

You could try a solution such as [BetterSettings](https://github.com/ElMassimo/better_settings) or [settingslogic](https://github.com/settingslogic/settingslogic) which provide a simple way to load YML files into a settings object.

Both libraries allow to easily access settings using method calls:

```rb
class Settings < BetterSettings
  source Rails.root.join('config/settings.yml'), namespace: :default
end
```

which would allow you to access settings like:

```rb
Settings.info.version # '2.0.0'
Settings.supported_languages.es # 'Español'
```

In this example, we are using `:default` as the namespace, but you could also use `Rails.env` to scope the settings to a specific environment.